# What is the best django practice to collect and store users' interest data?

Tags: django, django-models

I need to implement the simpliest users interest module in Django.

I have a very small web application with the ony search bar and a button.

The search bar is intended for an account number input. After pressing the button users get information about the entered account number

I need to collect and store data of users' interest by days. How many times data was searched everday.

```
eg.
|   day   |number of queries|
|22 Oct   | 7                |
|23 Oct   | 5                |
...
```

Django 2.2.1

I created the model:

models.py

```py
class LeadsNumber(models.Model):
    date_of_interest = models.DateField(blank=False)
    number_of_queries = models.IntegerField(blank=False, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["date"]
```

When the user input the data and press the button the function from view.py
look for the existing model and then update or create a new instance of the LeadsNumber model for the day when the account number was searched. I guess there is a better way for implementing such thing. Share your thoughts please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add date to the current_date so every time when the new objects created the it will set the current date

```
date_of_interest = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today())
```

And after the search function is performed you can increase the `number_of_queries` like this:

```
 obj = LeadsNumber.objects.get(pk=pk)
 obj.number_of_queries += 1
 obj.save()
```

Now you can query the number_of_queries with date like this:

```
queries = LeadsNumber.objects.filter(date_of_interest='some_date')
```

Comment: It works but instead of default=datetime.date.today() I had to use default=timezone.now from datetime